Kafka KRaft: 1 out of 3 brokers is always down
I'm trying to create a cluster with KRaft which has 3 brokers and 3 controllers. But each time one broker is going down while the previous downed one is getting up.
This is my docker configs:
version: "3.7"
services:
  controller-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: controller-1
    container_name: controller-1
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: controller
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: "1@controller-1:9093,2@controller-2:9093,3@controller-3:9093"
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: CONTROLLER://0.0.0.0:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /var/lib/kafka/data
      CLUSTER_ID: KixvqJ76Qn-xLPPrSfBQSw
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER # Set your generated UUID her
    volumes:
      - controller_1_data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    user: 1000:1000
    networks:
      - kafka-connector
    restart: always

  controller-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: controller-2
    container_name: controller-2
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 2
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: controller
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: "1@controller-1:9093,2@controller-2:9093,3@controller-3:9093"
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: CONTROLLER://0.0.0.0:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /var/lib/kafka/data
      CLUSTER_ID: KixvqJ76Qn-xLPPrSfBQSw
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
    volumes:
      - controller_2_data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    networks:
      - kafka-connector
    restart: always

  controller-3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: controller-3
    container_name: controller-3
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 3
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: controller
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: "1@controller-1:9093,2@controller-2:9093,3@controller-3:9093"
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: CONTROLLER://0.0.0.0:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /var/lib/kafka/data
      CLUSTER_ID: KixvqJ76Qn-xLPPrSfBQSw
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
    volumes:
      - controller_3_data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    networks:
      - kafka-connector
    restart: always

  kafka-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: kafka-1
    container_name: kafka-1
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 11
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 11
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: broker
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://192.168.18.2:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: "2@controller-2:9093,3@controller-3:9093"
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /var/lib/kafka/data
      CLUSTER_ID: KixvqJ76Qn-xLPPrSfBQSw
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 2
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
    volumes:
      - kafka_1_data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    networks:
      - kafka-connector
    restart: always

  kafka-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: kafka-2
    container_name: kafka-2
    ports:
      - 29093:29092
      - 9094:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 12
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 12
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: broker
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://192.168.18.2:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: "1@controller-1:9093,3@controller-3:9093"
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /var/lib/kafka/data
      CLUSTER_ID: KixvqJ76Qn-xLPPrSfBQSw
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 2
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
    volumes:
      - kafka_2_data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    networks:
      - kafka-connector
    restart: always

  kafka-3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: kafka-3
    container_name: kafka-3
    ports:
      - 29094:29092
      - 9096:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 13
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 13
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: broker
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://192.168.18.2:9096
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: "1@controller-1:9093,2@controller-2:9093"
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /var/lib/kafka/data
      CLUSTER_ID: KixvqJ76Qn-xLPPrSfBQSw
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 2
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
    volumes:
      - kafka_3_data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    networks:
      - kafka-connector
    restart: always

  debezium:
    image: debezium/connect:2.4
    depends_on:
      - kafka-1
      - kafka-2
      - kafka-3
    environment:
      - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka-1:29092,kafka-2:29093,kafka-3:29094
      - GROUP_ID=1
      - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
      - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
      - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    networks:
      - kafka-connector
    restart: always
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "1g"
        max-file: "5"

  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
    depends_on:
      - kafka-1
      - kafka-2
      - kafka-3
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_CONNECT: kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:9094,kafka-3:9096
    networks:
      - kafka-connector
    restart: always
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "1g"
        max-file: "5"
volumes:
  controller_1_data: ~
  controller_2_data: ~
  controller_3_data: ~
  kafka_1_data: ~
  kafka_2_data: ~
  kafka_3_data: ~

networks:
  kafka-connector:
    driver: bridge


Don't mind Debezium atm. I'm only trying to create the cluster and produce some messages.
The error I'm getting from broker-3 is this:
[2024-10-18 11:39:12,347] INFO [MetadataLoader id=13] initializeNewPublishers: the loader is still catching up because we still don't know the high water mark yet. (org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader)
[2024-10-18 11:39:12,420] INFO [RaftManager id=13] Registered the listener org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader@1574972196 (org.apache.kafka.raft.KafkaRaftClient)
[2024-10-18 11:39:12,455] INFO [MetadataLoader id=13] initializeNewPublishers: the loader is still catching up because we still don't know the high water mark yet. (org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader)
[2024-10-18 11:39:12,559] INFO [MetadataLoader id=13] initializeNewPublishers: the loader is still catching up because we still don't know the high water mark yet. (org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader)
[2024-10-18 11:39:12,695] INFO [MetadataLoader id=13] initializeNewPublishers: the loader is still catching up because we still don't know the high water mark yet. (org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader)
[2024-10-18 11:39:12,801] INFO [MetadataLoader id=13] initializeNewPublishers: the loader is still catching up because we still don't know the high water mark yet. (org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader)
[2024-10-18 11:39:12,901] INFO [MetadataLoader id=13] initializeNewPublishers: the loader is still catching up because we still don't know the high water mark yet. (org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader)
[2024-10-18 11:39:13,002] INFO [MetadataLoader id=13] initializeNewPublishers: the loader is still catching up because we still don't know the high water mark yet. (org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader)
[2024-10-18 11:39:13,063] ERROR Encountered fatal fault: Unexpected error in raft IO thread (org.apache.kafka.server.fault.ProcessTerminatingFaultHandler)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot transition to Follower with leaderId=3 and epoch=80 since it is not one of the voters [1, 2]
    at org.apache.kafka.raft.QuorumState.transitionToFollower(QuorumState.java:381)
    at org.apache.kafka.raft.KafkaRaftClient.transitionToFollower(KafkaRaftClient.java:518)
    at org.apache.kafka.raft.KafkaRaftClient.maybeTransition(KafkaRaftClient.java:1523)
    at org.apache.kafka.raft.KafkaRaftClient.maybeHandleCommonResponse(KafkaRaftClient.java:1473)
    at org.apache.kafka.raft.KafkaRaftClient.handleFetchResponse(KafkaRaftClient.java:1071)
    at org.apache.kafka.raft.KafkaRaftClient.handleResponse(KafkaRaftClient.java:1550)
    at org.apache.kafka.raft.KafkaRaftClient.handleInboundMessage(KafkaRaftClient.java:1676)
    at org.apache.kafka.raft.KafkaRaftClient.poll(KafkaRaftClient.java:2251)
    at kafka.raft.KafkaRaftManager$RaftIoThread.doWork(RaftManager.scala:64)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.util.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.java:127)


If broker-2 is down then the only difference is in this part:
[2024-10-18 11:43:54,404] ERROR Encountered fatal fault: Unexpected error in raft IO thread (org.apache.kafka.server.fault.ProcessTerminatingFaultHandler)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot transition to Follower with leaderId=2 and epoch=123 since it is not one of the voters [1, 3]


Is there something you hope to gain from multiple brokers and controllers on one docker host?

@OneCricketeer this cluster will be setup in production so naturally it will be on separate machines. At this time Im just trying to stabilize the configurations.

I find minikube + Strimzi easier to do that with than docker compose. Otherwise, if you're setting up VMs / cloud servers then Confluent maintains Ansible modules rather than containers (the containers have special startup scripts within them)

Well this will go inside k8s and after that it will be out of my hands, hopefully. But I'll make sure to pass this information to the devops guy. Thanks.

Sure, so like I said - Strimzi k8s operator is currently the best option for that

Each of your Quorum voters should be the same. Let Kafka decide which it chooses. Don't break them into [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]
The error comes from the one missing...
leaderId=3 and epoch=80 since it is not one of the voters [1, 2]
Cannot transition to Follower with leaderId=2 and epoch=123 since it is not one of the voters [1, 3]

You can easily do this in YAML by
KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: &kraft-voters "1@controller-1:9093,2@controller-2:9093,3@controller-3:9093"

...

KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: *kraft-voters


Also unclear what port 29092 is used for. You can remove those

Thanks for the answer. It started working now. I broke the voters in that order because I had an error something like broker-1 should not contain voter-1 (don't remember it well). One last question, from what I read in production each Kafka should has its own role, but yesterday when I talked to a coworker he suggested that Kafka's can be both broker and controller. Doing so gaining us resources but is it a best practice?

If you're willing to pay for the additional infrastructure, it's a good practice to separate them. Otherwise, in an upgrade scenario, you'll get 2/3 controllers up, for example, and that isn't a quorum... You could also use a cloud hosted kafka
